# Amplifying DAC output with common-emitter configuration

Tags: microcontroller, amplifier, dac, bias

In my current project setup I generate audio signals from my MCU's internal DAC. These audio signals are transferred to a speaker box with an internal amplifier via phone jack. To make the whole project more portable, I thought about giving my \$8\Omega/0.25W\$ speaker a try. Since the DAC should not output too much current I decided to add a class A audio amplifier with voltage divider biasing to the DAC's output.

The result would look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNtdHd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now my problem is that the DAC's output is always positive (between \$0.2V\$ and \$3.1V\$). Because C3 is an AC coupling capacitor, it will feed current back into the DAC when the audio signal becomes negative. **Will this damage the MCU?
And at which voltage level should I bias Q1?**

By the way, the MCU I'm using is the STM32H743ZI.

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you about the currents that are allowable to flow in and out of the DAC output?

Comment: Page 97 of the datasheet claims "output current sunk by any pin" as to be 20 mA. Under DAC characteristics there's no information about current besides +/-0mA allowable current injection.

Comment: To drive an 8ohm I’d suggest an emitter follower configuration since it has a lower output impedance

Comment: If you'd use a MOSFET (possibly followed by an end stage) and a high impedance bias circuit, your \$C_3\$ can be much smaller, reducing the negative current considerably.